# am trying to implement facebook login with flutter, but am getting these errors

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, kotlin, gradle

am having these errors after implementing facebook login in flutter. my code cant execute

e: C:/Users/HP/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/0c02c09b68f8e9b24bbbea025e769c0c/jetified-facebook-core-12.2.0-api.jar!/META-INF/facebook-core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/HP/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/24fa3aa8d2270e5eb067bbe36e9b7563/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/HP/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/38f92314671ee5340cbd0a5f71832b19/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/HP/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/54f0714bcfdfdf9279ff034535934d1c/jetified-facebook-common-12.2.0-api.jar!/META-INF/facebook-common_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
e: C:/Users/HP/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/77bab1911042ab2c6d5cc0b2e2ee053c/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 2):

`. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15`

If you're copy pasting the code from your existing project instead of doing that write the code again. Also fiddle with the kotlin version in project level build.gradle and change the kotlin version to 1.5.31 . This is a kotlin version issue and not necessary due to the facebook SDK integration
Do these:

1. Make sure that the Kotlin version of your IDE is the same as the version declared in your gradle.build file.
2. in  `flutter_app/android/build.gradle`  change `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31' or whatever is suitable

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by changing kotlin version at build.gradle

from :

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

to :

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
```

or whatever the latest version of kotlin that you can see [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#ide-support) and make sure to update Kotlin version to the latest in android studio as well